# apt-get works with private repository in Ubuntu 14 but fails with GPG error "signatures invalid" in Ubuntu 18

Tags: apt, repository, gnupg

My private package repository verifies OK in Ubuntu 14 LTS but fails verification in Ubuntu 18 LTS.
I failed to find the difference in the Ubuntu releases that causes the differerent behavior.

```
# Hostname, User, Password, Directory, Distribution, Component and Signature are my
# private values in the following code snippets:
apt-get update
Err:2 http://Hostname/Directory Distribution InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: Signature
```

apt configuration:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/Distribution.list
deb [arch=amd64] http://User:Password@Hostname/Directory/ Distribution Component
```

Downloading the `InRelease` file and verifying its signature manually succeeds (same result on Ubuntu 14 and Ubuntu 18):

```
wget --server-response -O- http://User:Password@Hostname/Directory/dists/Distribution/InRelease > ./InRelease
gpg --verify --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/Distribution.gpg ./InRelease

gpg: Signature made ...
gpg:                using RSA key ...
gpg: Good signature from "..." [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: SameSignatureAsInTheAptGetOutputAbove
```

How can I debug this to the root cause ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is caused by the silent rejection of insecure SHA-1 signatures in the new `apt` version in Ubuntu 18.
It seems that neither `gpg` nor `apt` are able to give an explicit warning about the outdated signature algorithm.
(If anybody knows how to produce such a warning, please comment here.)

Workaround is to put `digest-algo sha256` into `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` at the `aptly` package build server.
Found on https://github.com/aptly-dev/aptly/pull/366.
The SHA-256 signatures produced are compatible to `apt` in Ubuntu 14 and 18.

Long-term solution is to upgrade the `aptly` version that builds the repository.